# jenkins jobs that uploads a file into a python container

Tags: python, docker, jenkins, devops

am new into **jenkins**. am trying to do a **jenkins job** that uploads a file into a **python container** and then **reload the container**. could you guys please help me

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating your project you can add the command to upload and reload the python container under build->execute shell script.

Comment: https://www.stratoscale.com/blog/devops/using-jenkins-build-deploy-python-web-applications-part-2/